# Find int in base Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, where-clause

this is my query:

```
var caly = from m in stan.magazyn
           from g in stan.gdzie
           from p in stan.pracownik
           where m.Gdzie_Jest == g.ID_Miasta
           where m.Kto_Wprowadzil == p.ID_Pracownika
           where m.Gdzie_Jest == combobox_miasto
           orderby m.Marka, m.Model, m.IMEI
           where (m.ID.Contains(textBox13.Text)) 
                  ||  (m.Marka.Contains(textBox13.Text)) 
                  || (m.Model.Contains(textBox13.Text)) 
                  || (m.IMEI.Contains(textBox13.Text)) 
                  || (m.Kolor.Contains(textBox13.Text)) 
                  || (m.Od_Kogo.Contains(textBox13.Text)) 
                  || (m.Info.Contains(textBox13.Text))
          select new { m.ID, m.Marka, m.Model, m.IMEI, m.Kolor, m.Od_Kogo, Sklep = g.Nazwa, m.Data_Wprowadzenia, m.Cena_Kupna, Dodał = p.login, m.Info };
```

if I can do this: `(m.Marka.Contains(textBox13.Text))` and next, it's ok, because in my base this is string. I have problem when I want search ID `(m.ID.Contains(textBox13.Text))` because this is integer. what I must do in this situation?

Comment: Explain _"search ID"_. If the user enters "1", do you want to find the record with ID 1, or also 10, 11, 12, and so on?

Comment: If I put "1" I want see ID 1, 11, 15, 21,31,5551,133,412, etc. and other data for example model" nokia 3310".

Comment: if I put "3310" I want see for example id 3310, model 3310, and maybe IMEI 33104234823942, and 555331055555

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the value of `textBox13.Text` to a string. Ideally you would use `int.TryParse`:

```
int value = 0;
if(!int.TryParse(textBox13.Text,out value))
   throw new InvalidOperationException("textBox13 must contain a number");
```

and then

```
(m.ID.Contains(value))
```

(Side note: give your textboxes meaningful names - `textBox13` means nothing!)

---

Edit: Thanks to @CodeCaster who has pointed out an almost certain issue with the above - that your text box could be used to search string fields *or* numeric fields - in which case you probably dont want to throw an exception if parsing the textbox to an integer fails.

If this is the case you probably want two things

1. A boolean indicating whether you actually have a number
2. The string value parsed to a number

For example

```
int value = 0;
bool isNumericalSearch = int.TryParse(textBox13.Text,out value));
```

These values can then be used as part of your search query:

```
where (isNumericalSearch && m.ID == value) 
              || ((m.Marka.Contains(textBox13.Text)) 
              || (m.Model.Contains(textBox13.Text)) 
              || (m.IMEI.Contains(textBox13.Text)) 
              || (m.Kolor.Contains(textBox13.Text)) 
              || (m.Od_Kogo.Contains(textBox13.Text)) 
              || (m.Info.Contains(textBox13.Text)))
```

Comment: OP has a free search textbox that should be used on all fields. So if the user enters "fooproduct", you don't want to throw.

Comment: @CodeCaster I get your point, but are you just assuming that or is it specified anywhere?

Comment: If you look at OP's code, you see a bunch of ors (`||`). For example there's also an IMEI and Color field. When searching for "red", you don't want to throw. But of course, OP did not specify this. It's not that good a question.

Comment: Thanks for following my advice. :)

Comment: CodeCaster, has true. I want search all data in one textbox.

Comment: thats great! thansk :)

Comment: I think it's better to convert `ID` to string (some kind of inversion of what you do) and use Contains method normally like this `m.ID.ToString().Contains(textBox13.Text)`

Comment: @SSJ you said `If I put "1" I want see ID 1, 11, 15, 21,31,5551,133,412, etc`, so the code here won't do that. It just searches for exactly matched IDs.

Comment: @Jamiec you should read the comment the OP made under his question.

Comment: @Hopeless it was made after I answered this question, in fact i think it was after the OP marked this as their answer. *\*shrug\**

Comment: now I see, that Hopeless had true. Jamiec, dont wokr good :( if I put 316, I see only two imei, but dont see ID. sorry :D

Comment: I think you might be looking for @Zeeshan's answer below.

Comment: @SSJ you can try `m.ID.ToString().Contains(textBox13.Text)` instead, at least it should work in EF6, I've not experienced EF5 or earlier versions because I've just started with EF and jumped right to EF6.

Comment: And this is why you should specify the question accurately to start with!

Comment: @SSJ what version of EF are you using? I'm using EF6 and it's great that many not supported exceptions have gone away. If it's an earlier version, so using `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` should work for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [SqlFunction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) class to convert your `int` to `string`.

do somthing like:

```
(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)m.ID)).Contains(textBox13.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to cast the input value `textBox13.Text` into an int (let's call it `textBox13Integer`), then you can use `m.ID.Equals(textBox13Integer)` or `m.ID == textBox13Integer` in order to find your result by id.